# Python (2.7....) List problems

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

I am in need of some help, I'm currently doing an online python course and i can seem to get the desire result to complete the assignment.

basically, there is a text document which i need to call by using "raw_input" i then use"open()" function and then i have an empty "list()"

Now i run a "for" loop for each line in my .txt doc, i need to "r.strip()" all the white space, which leaves me with a 4 live .txt document ( .txt file will be at the bottom of the ask ) now i have to ".split()" those lines into words. now from the i need to loops through those words and ".append()" each word that isnt already in the list, then ".sort()" then print ... hopefully by that stage it looks as the desired output.

Just to make me feel a little better this is the first time im doing any sort of coding. so if you could explain where and why im going wrong that would be great.
CODE SO FAR - currently produces an error

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    a = line.rstrip()
    b = a.split()
    for words in b:
        if words not in lst:
print lst
```

.TXT DOCUMENT

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

p.s - Theres no point in changing the .txt to one line because the code it wont work in the grader. Ive tried (got the desired output, wrong code)

Please, you help would be greatly appreciated.

if there is anymore info you need, ill try provide it.

Comment: "currently produces an error". Which is, what exactly? Can you add the traceback to your question?

Comment: "".append()" each word that isnt already in the list". Python's [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) may be a lot more convenient for that.

Comment: Your `if` statement has no code block. Also, you're not doing anything with `lst` - it's just an empty list and never changes.

Comment: line 17, in <module>
    if words not in lst:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Tim Pietzcker, I know, but I'm extremely new at pyhon and im not entirely sure where im going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You will have an easier time (both here and in class) if you're _much_ more precise.  This:  "basically, there is a text document which i need to call by using "raw_input" i then use"open()" function and then i have an empty "list()"" ...is not precise at all.  In fact, I have no idea what it means, in part because you're using some terms incorrectly (like "call") and in part because the sentences don't relate to each other at all, but mostly because it's too vague to tell me anything useful, like what your _goal_ is.  Or what's gone wrong and what you'd expected.  Or what's happening at all.

Comment: ...in contrast, your code _is_ precise.  It still doesn't state your goal or any of the other necessary information, but at least it's precise.  The closer you can keep your speech, writing, and reading comprehension to that level of precision, the fewer misunderstandings you'll suffer through.  (This is why one of the most common comments on S.O. is to improve a question by including the code in question.  The next most common is probably asking what the goal was or what went wrong, as you've already encountered.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the file, add words to list, sort the list, and then print it.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    a = line.rstrip()
    b = a.split()
    for words in b:
        if words not in lst:
            lst.append(words)
lst.sort()
print lst
fh.close()
```

`lst.append(element)` will add the `element` into the list `lst`.

`lst.sort()` will sort the list `lst` alphabetically.

Check out the document => [Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: So in other words i was getting the traceback because i wasn't actually doing anything to the list itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list()
with open('inp.txt') as inp:
        for each_line in inp:
                a = each_line.strip()
                l += a.split()

print set(l)
```

use with keyword as it's a better practice as it would close your file after operation.and for the unique portion use set() which only accepts unique elements

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of `set` which is like a list but without duplicates. This means you don't have to check for duplicates yourself, since `set` will do it for you auto-magically.

eg:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = set()
for line in fh:
    a = line.rstrip()
    b = a.split()
    for words in b:
        lst.add(words)
lst = list(lst)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension to generate list, use set to remove duplicate entry

```
lst = [words for line in open(fname) for words in line.rstrip().split()]
lst = list(set(lst))
lst.sort()
print lst
```